# Wordpress Plugin CSS Order

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I think I've lost my mind...

I wrote a WP plugin a couple of years ago.   It consists of a couple of widgets, some short code, and code for a complete page.  No rocket science, really.

I'm doing a quick rewrite and have started running into a problem where the CSS for site's theme is being loaded AFTER the plugin CSS.  Of course, this makes it imposible to fine tune the plugin.

Why on earth would it do that?  Here's the code for enqueing the css.

```
**wp_enqueue_style("aa_remote", "http://domaind.com/css/site.css", false, "1.0");**
```

It has worked for two years!  and now it doesn't.

I did some digging and found that I may be able to use a dependancy, so I loaded the theme's stylesheet like this.

```
**wp_enqueue_style("aa_remote", "http://domaind.com/css/site.css", (array) get_stylesheet_uri(), "1.0");**
```

But that failed miserably.

I do a some hair left but I'm afraid it is in peril!

I'm sure I'm missing something basic... Any/All suggestions appreciated!  (walking away insn't an option!).

Comment: Depending on the structure of the `header.php` in the theme, you may or may not be able to control the load order. For example, if the theme stylesheet is included after the `wp_head()` function, you won't be able to load your CSS last even if you set a dependency in wp_enqueue_style.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach you can take is to utilize the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook/function to set a low priority for your stylesheet being processed. This way you can guarantee that styles load after all the default ones within WordPress plugin's code:

```
 function my_plugin_unique_style() {
     $base = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
     wp_enqueue_style( 'style-my-plugin-style', $base.'/styles.css' );
 }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_unique_style', 11 );
```

Of course you will have to modify this to use your plugin's css file name but this is a way to control the order your site's styles are loading. It's worth mentioning that if this still loads before another CSS file in the HEAD of the page you should bump up the number from 11 to some other higher number to move it down in priority and load later.

Comment: Thanks for this, just what I needed